# Hep on HttpOpenRequest() and other Wininet functions

Tags: c++, html, wininet

I'm still at it with saving random webpages from the web. After a slight modification to the code (calling HttpOpenRequest() differently), the program successfully downloaded a page that was being redirected. But I still can't get whatever webpage I want.

Example:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <wininet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>

#define SIZE 128


int main()

{

    HINTERNET Initialize,Connection,File;
    DWORD dwBytes;

    char ch;
    Initialize = InternetOpen("HTTPGET",INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT,NULL,NULL,0);

    Connection = InternetConnect(Initialize,"http://www.rottentomatoes.com",INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT,
    NULL,NULL,INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP,0,0);


    //File = HttpOpenRequest(Connection,NULL,"/index.html",NULL,NULL,NULL,0,0);

/**/

    File = HttpOpenRequest(Connection,
                                "GET",
                                "/index.jsp",
                                "HTTP/1.1",
                                NULL, NULL,
                                INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD | INTERNET_FLAG_EXISTING_CONNECT, 0);

    if(HttpSendRequest(File,NULL,0,NULL,0))
    {
        std::ofstream webSource;
        //webSource.open(strcat(argv[1], "__.html"));
        webSource.open("a.html");

        while(InternetReadFile(File,&ch,1,&dwBytes))
        {
            if(dwBytes != 1)break;
            webSource << ch;
        }
        webSource.close();
    }

    InternetCloseHandle(File);
    InternetCloseHandle(Connection);
    InternetCloseHandle(Initialize);

    return 0;
}
```

But when I try to download "http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/1209933-puss_in_boots/", I fail, that is, the program runs for less than a second and produces no output file.

What's the problem here, what function is causing this to happen?

Comment: What exactly is failing?
You should call GetLastError when one of the Wininet functions fails, to get a clue of what's happening.

Comment: @Simón this was 7 yrs ago I forgot.

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove "http://" from sample URL.

```
Connection = InternetConnect(Initialize,"www.rottentomatoes.com", INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT,
    NULL,NULL,INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP,0,0);
```

and make sure that filename in HttpOpenRequest is valid.